# building a good (mixed) linear model for agri-ecology data

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, model-checking, glmmtmb

I encountered an problem. I cannot build a good mixed linear model. For example,

```r
M <- glmmTMB(Numbers ~ MFS*CD*SNC+ #or you can use  lmer() whatever
# (MFS^2)+I(CD^2)+I(SNC^2) 
+(1|SITES/YEAR),  
           data=data,
           family="poisson"  # or  nbinom2
```

But it cannot pass through the model checking with `DHARMa` .

Can you help me to create suitable model?

Here is my dataset with `dput()`:
The data is agri-ecology data whose variable was renamed but didn't modify any value. And I'm sure that the nested structure is `YEAR/SITES`. Can you help me to build a good model which can be passed through model checking?

```
structure(list(YEAR = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2018", "2019", 
"2017"), class = "factor"), SITES = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L), .Label = c("CB1", "CB10", "CB11", 
"CB12", "CB13", "CB14", "CB15", "CB16", "CB17", "CB18", "CB19", 
"CB2", "CB20", "CB3", "CB4", "CB5", "CB6", "CB7", "CB8", "CB9", 
"CC1", "CC10", "CC11", "CC12", "CC13", "CC14", "CC15", "CC16", 
"CC17", "CC18", "CC2", "CC3", "CC4", "CC5", "CC6", "CC7", "CC8", 
"CC9", "CA1", "CA10", "CA11", "CA12", "CA13", "CA14", "CA15", 
"CA17", "CA18", "CA19", "CA2", "CA20", "CA3", "CA4", "CA5", "CA6", 
"CA7", "CA9", "CA16", "CA8"), class = "factor"), Numbers = c(7L, 
21L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 18L, 16L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 12L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 11L, 14L, 20L, 3L, 
10L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 12L, 5L, 11L, 8L, 12L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 13L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 10L, 8L, 3L, 47L, 
54L, 75L, 22L, 27L, 29L, 37L, 49L, 54L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 16L, 22L, 
2L, 12L, 25L, 9L, 24L, 23L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 17L, 46L, 21L, 35L, 18L, 
11L, 18L, 21L, 13L, 18L, 16L, 20L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 15L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
6L, 0L, 21L, 9L, 7L, 15L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 14L, 18L, 26L, 57L, 
93L, 80L, 47L, 23L, 38L, 25L, 14L, 6L, 14L, 11L, 17L, 0L, 21L, 
15L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 13L, 26L, 52L, 41L, 40L, 32L, 
12L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 20L, 12L, 26L, 41L, 42L, 27L, 12L, 11L, 
17L, 9L, 27L, 28L, 30L, 16L, 16L, 10L, 21L, 13L, 14L, 31L, 25L, 
17L, 17L, 45L, 55L, 25L, 76L, 59L, 64L, 24L, 41L, 49L, 53L, 46L, 
60L, 16L, 15L, 17L, 10L, 13L, 23L, 13L, 16L, 11L, 9L, 25L, 13L, 
12L, 18L, 41L, 31L, 33L, 22L, 14L, 76L, 52L, 45L, 56L, 6L, 14L, 
19L, 29L, 40L, 39L, 26L, 20L, 46L, 12L, 33L, 9L, 26L, 23L, 20L, 
18L, 21L, 13L, 61L, 57L, 36L, 17L, 22L, 26L, 37L, 45L, 39L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 18L, 16L, 19L, 
0L, 48L, 32L, 36L, 31L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 0L), MFS = structure(c(-0.31668, 
-0.31668, -0.31668, -0.91004, -0.91004, -0.91004, -1.35102, -1.35102, 
-1.35102, -0.37686, -0.37686, -0.37686, 0.51278, 0.51278, 0.51278, 
-0.92231, -0.92231, -0.92231, -1.38047, -1.38047, -1.38047, -0.67477, 
-0.67477, -0.67477, -0.67358, -0.67358, -0.67358, 1.27997, 1.27997, 
1.27997, 0.92923, 0.92923, 0.92923, 0.81028, 0.81028, 0.81028, 
0.70852, 0.70852, 0.70852, 1.74376, 1.74376, 1.74376, -0.63887, 
-0.63887, -0.63887, -0.31126, -0.31126, -0.31126, -1.17257, -1.17257, 
-1.17257, -1.04054, -1.04054, -1.04054, -0.5083, -0.5083, -0.5083, 
-0.76518, -0.76518, -0.76518, -0.31668, -0.31668, -0.31668, -0.91004, 
-0.91004, -0.91004, -1.35102, -1.35102, -1.35102, -0.37686, -0.37686, 
-0.37686, 0.51278, 0.51278, 0.51278, -0.92231, -0.92231, -0.92231, 
-1.38047, -1.38047, -0.67477, -0.67477, -0.67477, -0.67358, -0.67358, 
-0.67358, 1.27997, 0.92923, 0.92923, 0.92923, 0.81028, 0.81028, 
0.81028, 0.70852, 0.70852, 1.74376, 1.74376, 1.74376, -0.63887, 
-0.63887, -0.63887, -0.31126, -0.31126, -0.31126, -1.17257, -1.17257, 
-1.04054, -1.04054, -1.04054, -0.5083, -0.5083, -0.5083, -0.76518, 
-0.76518, -0.76518, -0.31668, -0.31668, -0.31668, -0.91004, -1.35102, 
-1.35102, -1.35102, -0.37686, -0.37686, -0.37686, 0.51278, 0.51278, 
0.51278, -0.92231, -0.92231, -0.92231, -1.38047, -1.38047, -1.38047, 
-0.67477, -0.67477, -0.67477, -0.67358, -0.67358, -0.67358, 1.27997, 
1.27997, 1.27997, 0.92923, 0.92923, 0.92923, 0.81028, 0.81028, 
0.81028, 0.70852, 0.70852, 0.70852, 1.74376, 1.74376, 1.74376, 
-0.63887, -0.63887, -0.63887, -0.31126, -0.31126, -0.31126, -1.17257, 
-1.17257, -1.17257, -1.04054, -1.04054, -1.04054, -0.5083, -0.5083, 
-0.5083, -0.76518, -0.76518, -0.76518, -0.31668, -0.31668, -0.31668, 
-0.91004, -0.91004, -0.91004, -1.35102, -1.35102, -1.35102, -0.37686, 
-0.37686, -0.37686, 0.51278, 0.51278, 0.51278, -0.92231, -0.92231, 
-0.92231, -1.38047, -1.38047, -0.67477, -0.67477, -0.67477, -0.67358, 
-0.67358, -0.67358, 1.27997, 1.27997, 1.27997, 0.92923, 0.92923, 
0.92923, 0.81028, 0.81028, 0.81028, 0.70852, 0.70852, 0.70852, 
1.74376, 1.74376, 1.74376, -0.63887, -0.63887, -0.63887, -0.31126, 
-0.31126, -0.31126, -1.17257, -1.17257, -1.17257, -1.04054, -1.04054, 
-1.04054, -0.5083, -0.5083, -0.5083, -0.76518, -0.76518, -0.76518, 
-0.59511, -0.59511, -0.59511, 0.1995, 0.1995, 0.1995, -0.93013, 
-0.93013, -0.93013, -0.47282, -0.47282, -0.47282, -1.39138, -1.39138, 
-1.39138, 0.34058, 0.34058, 0.34058, 1.40673, 1.40673, 1.40673, 
1.41673, 1.41673, 1.41673, 1.19088, 1.19088, 1.19088, 1.04958, 
1.04958, 1.04958, 0.31309, 0.31309, 0.31309, 0.87115, 0.87115, 
0.87115, -1.24734, -1.24734, -1.24734, -1.14108, -1.14108, -1.14108, 
-0.30191, -0.30191, -0.30191, -1.06399, -1.06399, -1.06399, -1.09717, 
-1.09717, -1.09717, 0.23201, 0.23201, 0.23201, -0.59511, -0.59511, 
-0.59511, 0.1995, 0.1995, 0.1995, -0.93013, -0.93013, -0.93013, 
-0.47282, -0.47282, -0.47282, -1.39138, -1.39138, -1.39138, 0.34058, 
0.34058, 0.34058, 1.40673, 1.40673, 1.40673, 1.41673, 1.41673, 
1.41673, 1.19088, 1.19088, 1.19088, 0.31309, 0.31309, 0.31309, 
0.87115, 0.87115, 0.87115, -1.24734, -1.24734, -1.24734, -1.14108, 
-1.14108, -1.14108, -0.30191, -0.30191, -0.30191, -1.06399, -1.06399, 
-1.06399, -1.09717, -1.09717, -1.09717, 0.23201, 0.23201, 0.23201
), "`scaled:center`" = 0.531172306358715, "`scaled:scale`" = 0.1321853801893, .Dim = c(337L, 
1L)), CD = structure(c(-0.45468, -0.45468, -0.45468, 0.65983, 
0.65983, 0.65983, 0.95445, 0.95445, 0.95445, -0.13926, -0.13926, 
-0.13926, -0.62844, -0.62844, -0.62844, -0.78665, -0.78665, -0.78665, 
0.07387, 0.07387, 0.07387, -0.31302, -0.31302, -0.31302, -0.78941, 
-0.78941, -0.78941, -1.04391, -1.04391, -1.04391, -0.01615, -0.01615, 
-0.01615, 1.04371, 1.04371, 1.04371, 0.57985, 0.57985, 0.57985, 
-1.08127, -1.08127, -1.08127, 1.39524, 1.39524, 1.39524, 0.88148, 
0.88148, 0.88148, 1.22399, 1.22399, 1.22399, 0.81053, 0.81053, 
0.81053, 1.34534, 1.34534, 1.34534, 0.87095, 0.87095, 0.87095, 
-0.45468, -0.45468, -0.45468, 0.65983, 0.65983, 0.65983, 0.95445, 
0.95445, 0.95445, -0.13926, -0.13926, -0.13926, -0.62844, -0.62844, 
-0.62844, -0.78665, -0.78665, -0.78665, 0.07387, 0.07387, -0.31302, 
-0.31302, -0.31302, -0.78941, -0.78941, -0.78941, -1.04391, -0.01615, 
-0.01615, -0.01615, 1.04371, 1.04371, 1.04371, 0.57985, 0.57985, 
-1.08127, -1.08127, -1.08127, 1.39524, 1.39524, 1.39524, 0.88148, 
0.88148, 0.88148, 1.22399, 1.22399, 0.81053, 0.81053, 0.81053, 
1.34534, 1.34534, 1.34534, 0.87095, 0.87095, 0.87095, -0.45468, 
-0.45468, -0.45468, 0.65983, 0.95445, 0.95445, 0.95445, -0.13926, 
-0.13926, -0.13926, -0.62844, -0.62844, -0.62844, -0.78665, -0.78665, 
-0.78665, 0.07387, 0.07387, 0.07387, -0.31302, -0.31302, -0.31302, 
-0.78941, -0.78941, -0.78941, -1.04391, -1.04391, -1.04391, -0.01615, 
-0.01615, -0.01615, 1.04371, 1.04371, 1.04371, 0.57985, 0.57985, 
0.57985, -1.08127, -1.08127, -1.08127, 1.39524, 1.39524, 1.39524, 
0.88148, 0.88148, 0.88148, 1.22399, 1.22399, 1.22399, 0.81053, 
0.81053, 0.81053, 1.34534, 1.34534, 1.34534, 0.87095, 0.87095, 
0.87095, -0.45468, -0.45468, -0.45468, 0.65983, 0.65983, 0.65983, 
0.95445, 0.95445, 0.95445, -0.13926, -0.13926, -0.13926, -0.62844, 
-0.62844, -0.62844, -0.78665, -0.78665, -0.78665, 0.07387, 0.07387, 
-0.31302, -0.31302, -0.31302, -0.78941, -0.78941, -0.78941, -1.04391, 
-1.04391, -1.04391, -0.01615, -0.01615, -0.01615, 1.04371, 1.04371, 
1.04371, 0.57985, 0.57985, 0.57985, -1.08127, -1.08127, -1.08127, 
1.39524, 1.39524, 1.39524, 0.88148, 0.88148, 0.88148, 1.22399, 
1.22399, 1.22399, 0.81053, 0.81053, 0.81053, 1.34534, 1.34534, 
1.34534, 0.87095, 0.87095, 0.87095, 1.39298, 1.39298, 1.39298, 
0.34943, 0.34943, 0.34943, 0.42214, 0.42214, 0.42214, 1.25382, 
1.25382, 1.25382, 1.56248, 1.56248, 1.56248, -0.38121, -0.38121, 
-0.38121, 0.61119, 0.61119, 0.61119, -0.56199, -0.56199, -0.56199, 
-2.47309, -2.47309, -2.47309, -1.08377, -1.08377, -1.08377, -1.68629, 
-1.68629, -1.68629, -2.24267, -2.24267, -2.24267, 0.30179, 0.30179, 
0.30179, -1.60781, -1.60781, -1.60781, -0.69338, -0.69338, -0.69338, 
0.19873, 0.19873, 0.19873, 0.41186, 0.41186, 0.41186, -1.20613, 
-1.20613, -1.20613, 1.39298, 1.39298, 1.39298, 0.34943, 0.34943, 
0.34943, 0.42214, 0.42214, 0.42214, 1.25382, 1.25382, 1.25382, 
1.56248, 1.56248, 1.56248, -0.38121, -0.38121, -0.38121, 0.61119, 
0.61119, 0.61119, -0.56199, -0.56199, -0.56199, -2.47309, -2.47309, 
-2.47309, -1.68629, -1.68629, -1.68629, -2.24267, -2.24267, -2.24267, 
0.30179, 0.30179, 0.30179, -1.60781, -1.60781, -1.60781, -0.69338, 
-0.69338, -0.69338, 0.19873, 0.19873, 0.19873, 0.41186, 0.41186, 
0.41186, -1.20613, -1.20613, -1.20613), "`scaled:center`" = 1.67953928571429, "`scaled:scale`" = 0.398828225808178, .Dim = c(337L, 
1L)), SNC = structure(c(-0.5932, -0.5932, -0.5932, 1.28526, 1.28526, 
1.28526, 0.32736, 0.32736, 0.32736, 0.34083, 0.34083, 0.34083, 
-0.06558, -0.06558, -0.06558, -0.26579, -0.26579, -0.26579, 0.24139, 
0.24139, 0.24139, -0.28049, -0.28049, -0.28049, 1.74292, 1.74292, 
1.74292, 4.07313, 4.07313, 4.07313, -0.55499, -0.55499, -0.55499, 
-0.71751, -0.71751, -0.71751, 0.07127, 0.07127, 0.07127, -0.08624, 
-0.08624, -0.08624, -0.82514, -0.82514, -0.82514, -0.98999, -0.98999, 
-0.98999, -0.89201, -0.89201, -0.89201, -0.44828, -0.44828, -0.44828, 
-0.91701, -0.91701, -0.91701, -0.57677, -0.57677, -0.57677, -0.5932, 
-0.5932, -0.5932, 1.28526, 1.28526, 1.28526, 0.32736, 0.32736, 
0.32736, 0.34083, 0.34083, 0.34083, -0.06558, -0.06558, -0.06558, 
-0.26579, -0.26579, -0.26579, 0.24139, 0.24139, -0.28049, -0.28049, 
-0.28049, 1.74292, 1.74292, 1.74292, 4.07313, -0.55499, -0.55499, 
-0.55499, -0.71751, -0.71751, -0.71751, 0.07127, 0.07127, -0.08624, 
-0.08624, -0.08624, -0.82514, -0.82514, -0.82514, -0.98999, -0.98999, 
-0.98999, -0.89201, -0.89201, -0.44828, -0.44828, -0.44828, -0.91701, 
-0.91701, -0.91701, -0.57677, -0.57677, -0.57677, -0.5932, -0.5932, 
-0.5932, 1.28526, 0.32736, 0.32736, 0.32736, 0.34083, 0.34083, 
0.34083, -0.06558, -0.06558, -0.06558, -0.26579, -0.26579, -0.26579, 
0.24139, 0.24139, 0.24139, -0.28049, -0.28049, -0.28049, 1.74292, 
1.74292, 1.74292, 4.07313, 4.07313, 4.07313, -0.55499, -0.55499, 
-0.55499, -0.71751, -0.71751, -0.71751, 0.07127, 0.07127, 0.07127, 
-0.08624, -0.08624, -0.08624, -0.82514, -0.82514, -0.82514, -0.98999, 
-0.98999, -0.98999, -0.89201, -0.89201, -0.89201, -0.44828, -0.44828, 
-0.44828, -0.91701, -0.91701, -0.91701, -0.57677, -0.57677, -0.57677, 
-0.5932, -0.5932, -0.5932, 1.28526, 1.28526, 1.28526, 0.32736, 
0.32736, 0.32736, 0.34083, 0.34083, 0.34083, -0.06558, -0.06558, 
-0.06558, -0.26579, -0.26579, -0.26579, 0.24139, 0.24139, -0.28049, 
-0.28049, -0.28049, 1.74292, 1.74292, 1.74292, 4.07313, 4.07313, 
4.07313, -0.55499, -0.55499, -0.55499, -0.71751, -0.71751, -0.71751, 
0.07127, 0.07127, 0.07127, -0.08624, -0.08624, -0.08624, -0.82514, 
-0.82514, -0.82514, -0.98999, -0.98999, -0.98999, -0.89201, -0.89201, 
-0.89201, -0.44828, -0.44828, -0.44828, -0.91701, -0.91701, -0.91701, 
-0.57677, -0.57677, -0.57677, 0.54483, 0.54483, 0.54483, -0.44001, 
-0.44001, -0.44001, -0.13542, -0.13542, -0.13542, -0.40511, -0.40511, 
-0.40511, -0.7626, -0.7626, -0.7626, -0.03031, -0.03031, -0.03031, 
0.22905, 0.22905, 0.22905, -0.42241, -0.42241, -0.42241, 2.11259, 
2.11259, 2.11259, 0.63598, 0.63598, 0.63598, 1.1605, 1.1605, 
1.1605, 0.49949, 0.49949, 0.49949, -0.17903, -0.17903, -0.17903, 
1.64496, 1.64496, 1.64496, -0.97751, -0.97751, -0.97751, -0.53011, 
-0.53011, -0.53011, 0.22539, 0.22539, 0.22539, 0.57934, 0.57934, 
0.57934, 0.54483, 0.54483, 0.54483, -0.44001, -0.44001, -0.44001, 
-0.13542, -0.13542, -0.13542, -0.40511, -0.40511, -0.40511, -0.7626, 
-0.7626, -0.7626, -0.03031, -0.03031, -0.03031, 0.22905, 0.22905, 
0.22905, -0.42241, -0.42241, -0.42241, 2.11259, 2.11259, 2.11259, 
1.1605, 1.1605, 1.1605, 0.49949, 0.49949, 0.49949, -0.17903, 
-0.17903, -0.17903, 1.64496, 1.64496, 1.64496, -0.97751, -0.97751, 
-0.97751, -0.53011, -0.53011, -0.53011, 0.22539, 0.22539, 0.22539, 
0.57934, 0.57934, 0.57934), "`scaled:center`" = 16.3174214285714, "`scaled:scale`" = 5.93223200247334, .Dim = c(337L, 
1L)), Latitude = c(41.17633, 41.17633, 41.17633, 41.16153, 41.16153, 
41.16153, 41.12162, 41.12162, 41.12162, 41.16687, 41.16687, 41.16687, 
41.10928, 41.10928, 41.10928, 41.07349, 41.07349, 41.07349, 41.03278, 
41.03278, 41.03278, 40.97858, 40.97858, 40.97858, 41.03571, 41.03571, 
41.03571, 40.80911, 40.80911, 40.80911, 40.80239, 40.80239, 40.80239, 
40.82871, 40.82871, 40.82871, 41.02167, 41.02167, 41.02167, 40.98108, 
40.98108, 40.98108, 40.98334, 40.98334, 40.98334, 40.91264, 40.91264, 
40.91264, 41.02665, 41.02665, 41.02665, 40.99086, 40.99086, 40.99086, 
40.97544, 40.97544, 40.97544, 41.00486, 41.00486, 41.00486, 41.17633, 
41.17633, 41.17633, 41.16153, 41.16153, 41.16153, 41.12162, 41.12162, 
41.12162, 41.16687, 41.16687, 41.16687, 41.10928, 41.10928, 41.10928, 
41.07349, 41.07349, 41.07349, 41.03278, 41.03278, 40.97858, 40.97858, 
40.97858, 41.03571, 41.03571, 41.03571, 40.80911, 40.80239, 40.80239, 
40.80239, 40.82871, 40.82871, 40.82871, 41.02167, 41.02167, 40.98108, 
40.98108, 40.98108, 40.98334, 40.98334, 40.98334, 40.91264, 40.91264, 
40.91264, 41.02665, 41.02665, 40.99086, 40.99086, 40.99086, 40.97544, 
40.97544, 40.97544, 41.00486, 41.00486, 41.00486, 41.17633, 41.17633, 
41.17633, 41.16153, 41.12162, 41.12162, 41.12162, 41.16687, 41.16687, 
41.16687, 41.10928, 41.10928, 41.10928, 41.07349, 41.07349, 41.07349, 
41.03278, 41.03278, 41.03278, 40.97858, 40.97858, 40.97858, 41.03571, 
41.03571, 41.03571, 40.80911, 40.80911, 40.80911, 40.80239, 40.80239, 
40.80239, 40.82871, 40.82871, 40.82871, 41.02167, 41.02167, 41.02167, 
40.98108, 40.98108, 40.98108, 40.98334, 40.98334, 40.98334, 40.91264, 
40.91264, 40.91264, 41.02665, 41.02665, 41.02665, 40.99086, 40.99086, 
40.99086, 40.97544, 40.97544, 40.97544, 41.00486, 41.00486, 41.00486, 
41.17633, 41.17633, 41.17633, 41.16153, 41.16153, 41.16153, 41.12162, 
41.12162, 41.12162, 41.16687, 41.16687, 41.16687, 41.10928, 41.10928, 
41.10928, 41.07349, 41.07349, 41.07349, 41.03278, 41.03278, 40.97858, 
40.97858, 40.97858, 41.03571, 41.03571, 41.03571, 40.80911, 40.80911, 
40.80911, 40.80239, 40.80239, 40.80239, 40.82871, 40.82871, 40.82871, 
41.02167, 41.02167, 41.02167, 40.98108, 40.98108, 40.98108, 40.98334, 
40.98334, 40.98334, 40.91264, 40.91264, 40.91264, 41.02665, 41.02665, 
41.02665, 40.99086, 40.99086, 40.99086, 40.97544, 40.97544, 40.97544, 
41.00486, 41.00486, 41.00486, 41.02153, 41.02153, 41.02153, 40.99896, 
40.99896, 40.99896, 40.97013, 40.97013, 40.97013, 40.92366, 40.92366, 
40.92366, 40.88676, 40.88676, 40.88676, 40.85327, 40.85327, 40.85327, 
40.86955, 40.86955, 40.86955, 40.82965, 40.82965, 40.82965, 40.85355, 
40.85355, 40.85355, 40.92547, 40.92547, 40.92547, 40.89467, 40.89467, 
40.89467, 40.90359, 40.90359, 40.90359, 41.01632, 41.01632, 41.01632, 
41.04501, 41.04501, 41.04501, 41.04973, 41.04973, 41.04973, 41.08329, 
41.08329, 41.08329, 41.12912, 41.12912, 41.12912, 41.17237, 41.17237, 
41.17237, 41.02153, 41.02153, 41.02153, 40.99896, 40.99896, 40.99896, 
40.97013, 40.97013, 40.97013, 40.92366, 40.92366, 40.92366, 40.88676, 
40.88676, 40.88676, 40.85327, 40.85327, 40.85327, 40.86955, 40.86955, 
40.86955, 40.82965, 40.82965, 40.82965, 40.85355, 40.85355, 40.85355, 
40.89467, 40.89467, 40.89467, 40.90359, 40.90359, 40.90359, 41.01632, 
41.01632, 41.01632, 41.04501, 41.04501, 41.04501, 41.04973, 41.04973, 
41.04973, 41.08329, 41.08329, 41.08329, 41.12912, 41.12912, 41.12912, 
41.17237, 41.17237, 41.17237), Longitude = c(80.41081, 80.41081, 
80.41081, 80.47889, 80.47889, 80.47889, 80.48463, 80.48463, 80.48463, 
80.52739, 80.52739, 80.52739, 80.56703, 80.56703, 80.56703, 80.53371, 
80.53371, 80.53371, 80.55772, 80.55772, 80.55772, 80.57384, 80.57384, 
80.57384, 80.48125, 80.48125, 80.48125, 80.56282, 80.56282, 80.56282, 
80.46875, 80.46875, 80.46875, 80.41125, 80.41125, 80.41125, 80.35851, 
80.35851, 80.35851, 80.39885, 80.39885, 80.39885, 80.33922, 80.33922, 
80.33922, 80.3234, 80.3234, 80.3234, 80.30015, 80.30015, 80.30015, 
80.26168, 80.26168, 80.26168, 80.22535, 80.22535, 80.22535, 80.20558, 
80.20558, 80.20558, 80.41081, 80.41081, 80.41081, 80.47889, 80.47889, 
80.47889, 80.48463, 80.48463, 80.48463, 80.52739, 80.52739, 80.52739, 
80.56703, 80.56703, 80.56703, 80.53371, 80.53371, 80.53371, 80.55772, 
80.55772, 80.57384, 80.57384, 80.57384, 80.48125, 80.48125, 80.48125, 
80.56282, 80.46875, 80.46875, 80.46875, 80.41125, 80.41125, 80.41125, 
80.35851, 80.35851, 80.39885, 80.39885, 80.39885, 80.33922, 80.33922, 
80.33922, 80.3234, 80.3234, 80.3234, 80.30015, 80.30015, 80.26168, 
80.26168, 80.26168, 80.22535, 80.22535, 80.22535, 80.20558, 80.20558, 
80.20558, 80.41081, 80.41081, 80.41081, 80.47889, 80.48463, 80.48463, 
80.48463, 80.52739, 80.52739, 80.52739, 80.56703, 80.56703, 80.56703, 
80.53371, 80.53371, 80.53371, 80.55772, 80.55772, 80.55772, 80.57384, 
80.57384, 80.57384, 80.48125, 80.48125, 80.48125, 80.56282, 80.56282, 
80.56282, 80.46875, 80.46875, 80.46875, 80.41125, 80.41125, 80.41125, 
80.35851, 80.35851, 80.35851, 80.39885, 80.39885, 80.39885, 80.33922, 
80.33922, 80.33922, 80.3234, 80.3234, 80.3234, 80.30015, 80.30015, 
80.30015, 80.26168, 80.26168, 80.26168, 80.22535, 80.22535, 80.22535, 
80.20558, 80.20558, 80.20558, 80.41081, 80.41081, 80.41081, 80.47889, 
80.47889, 80.47889, 80.48463, 80.48463, 80.48463, 80.52739, 80.52739, 
80.52739, 80.56703, 80.56703, 80.56703, 80.53371, 80.53371, 80.53371, 
80.55772, 80.55772, 80.57384, 80.57384, 80.57384, 80.48125, 80.48125, 
80.48125, 80.56282, 80.56282, 80.56282, 80.46875, 80.46875, 80.46875, 
80.41125, 80.41125, 80.41125, 80.35851, 80.35851, 80.35851, 80.39885, 
80.39885, 80.39885, 80.33922, 80.33922, 80.33922, 80.3234, 80.3234, 
80.3234, 80.30015, 80.30015, 80.30015, 80.26168, 80.26168, 80.26168, 
80.22535, 80.22535, 80.22535, 80.20558, 80.20558, 80.20558, 80.34978, 
80.34978, 80.34978, 80.32717, 80.32717, 80.32717, 80.37382, 80.37382, 
80.37382, 80.3908, 80.3908, 80.3908, 80.38736, 80.38736, 80.38736, 
80.43401, 80.43401, 80.43401, 80.47639, 80.47639, 80.47639, 80.49735, 
80.49735, 80.49735, 80.51818, 80.51818, 80.51818, 80.50315, 80.50315, 
80.50315, 80.51506, 80.51506, 80.51506, 80.55928, 80.55928, 80.55928, 
80.55103, 80.55103, 80.55103, 80.52075, 80.52075, 80.52075, 80.47118, 
80.47118, 80.47118, 80.5078, 80.5078, 80.5078, 80.48428, 80.48428, 
80.48428, 80.40629, 80.40629, 80.40629, 80.34978, 80.34978, 80.34978, 
80.32717, 80.32717, 80.32717, 80.37382, 80.37382, 80.37382, 80.3908, 
80.3908, 80.3908, 80.38736, 80.38736, 80.38736, 80.43401, 80.43401, 
80.43401, 80.47639, 80.47639, 80.47639, 80.49735, 80.49735, 80.49735, 
80.51818, 80.51818, 80.51818, 80.51506, 80.51506, 80.51506, 80.55928, 
80.55928, 80.55928, 80.55103, 80.55103, 80.55103, 80.52075, 80.52075, 
80.52075, 80.47118, 80.47118, 80.47118, 80.5078, 80.5078, 80.5078, 
80.48428, 80.48428, 80.48428, 80.40629, 80.40629, 80.40629)), row.names = c(NA, 
-337L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]